# iOS の Safari にて <a href="xxx" target="_blank" rel="noopener"></a>で別ウィンドウにてリンクを開きたい

Tags: javascript, ios, html, safari

iOSのSafariにおいて、`<a>タグ`の挙動について質問です。

**実現したいこと**
以下のように、ボタンをクリックするとJavaScript(React)でdownload属性を設定した`<a>タグ`を生成し、サーバに配置してあるPDFファイルをダウンロードするコードを書きました。
ここで、iOS13以前のSafariはdownload属性が未実装のようなので、iOSに限り別ウィンドウでPDFを表示させたいです。

**困っていること**
しかし、iOS12でリンクをクリックすると別ウィンドウが開かれず、同一ウィンドウでリンクを実装したページの親ページに遷移してしまいます。
また、iOS13でも同じ挙動です。

意図通りに動かす方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授いただけたら幸いです。

jsxファイル

```
<a onClick={this.props.downloadPdf}>ファイルをDL</a>
```

jsファイル

```
  const downloadPdf = () => props.dispatch(getPDF()).then((res) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(res.payload.data);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'test.pdf';
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.rel = 'noopener';
    a.click();
    a.remove();

    setTimeout(() => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }, 1000);
  });
```

＊ 以下の環境でダウンロード成功
OS: mac
ブラウザ: Safari, Chrome

Comment: これは、iOS Safariの場合はPDFのダウンロードボタンを`<a href="file.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a>`とするでは事足りないでしょうか？それとも、iOS Safariの場合でも無遷移ダウンロードさせたいということでしょうか？

Comment: 前者の方法で対応できました。アドバイス誠にありがとうございました。